# Git refusing to create/use dir in other submodule's dir

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to update git submodules recursively using `git submodule update --recursive --remote --init`. The modules structure is:

- A

  - B

    - C/master
    - C/backend
    - C/frontend

All branches in use in C are orphan with completely separated code...

All repos are private, but I´m the owner.

This is the message I get everytime. (Tried syncing, using git://, updating first without recursion)

> Failed to clone 'C/master'. Retry scheduled

> error: submodule git dir 'F:/Docs/A/.git/modules/B/modules/C/backend' is inside git dir 'F:/Docs/A/.git/modules/B/modules/C'

> fatal: refusing to create/use 'F:/Docs/A/.git/modules/B/modules/C/backend' in another submodule's git dir

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the repository name and path name were differnt, git add named the submodule by path name, not direcotory name and changing the submodules' name in .gitmodules in repo B fixed this...

Previosly:

```
[submodule "Folder/master"]
    path = Folder/master
    url = https://github.com/tomkys144/C
    branch = master
[submodule "Folder/backend"]
    path = "Folder/backend
    url = https://github.com/tomkys144/C
    branch = backend
[submodule "Folder/frontend"]
    path = Folder/frontend
    url = https://github.com/tomkys144/C
    branch = frontend
```

Fixed:

```
[submodule "C/master"]
    path = Folder/master
    url = https://github.com/tomkys144/C
    branch = master
[submodule "C/backend"]
    path = "Folder/backend
    url = https://github.com/tomkys144/C
    branch = backend
[submodule "C/frontend"]
    path = Folder/frontend
    url = https://github.com/tomkys144/C
    branch = frontend
```